# Verify that a variable is a number

Tags: batch-file

How does one verify that a variable is a number in a batch file?

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 10934, 495832945, 4395893428 ->  true
Apple, Orange, Animal, Red, Sky, Leaf -> false
```

Comment: Integers only, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo %variable%| FINDSTR /R /X " *[0-9]* *" >nul 2>&1 && echo IT IS A NUMBER
echo %variable%| FINDSTR /R /X " *[0-9]* *" >nul 2>&1 || echo IT IS NOT A NUMBER
```

Comment: Good, I found meanwhile new answer, but you deserve answering vote though. I will do it as soon as SO system will allow me to do it (5 mins)

Comment: Your answer doesn't work properly. After putting non-numbers, numbers doesn't trigger your script anymore.

Comment: I've edited the answer.There was an extra space before the first pipe.

Comment: After entered non-number, and then entered a number, it still said that it wasn't number. You have now edited answer, but I have another script, thank you though, and I'll upvote it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found on StackOverflow.com

```
set /p Input1=Enter number: 
set /a Input2=%Input1% * 1
if "%Input2%"=="0" echo It is not a number.
```

It doesn't work with 0 to 0.9 numbers.

Comment: "Answer found on StackOverflow.com" - Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=isnumber_nt [ [Alt Link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/isnumber_nt.txt) ]

```
:: Positive decimal
SET RC=10
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%A IN ("%Value%") DO SET RC=0
IF %RC% EQU 10 EXIT /B 10
```